# Нетерпеливая загрузка и отношения других моделей

Tags: php, laravel

Имеется таблица basket_items, которая имеет полиморфную связь с другими моделями. Как мне сделать так, что если в Модели есть другая связь, то что бы она тоже вывелась при запросе.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот тут второй items имеет event_id и city_id, как мне получить их модели?

Я смог получить отношение для этого элемента

```
 $basket = Basket::with('items.entity')->with(['items' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('entity_type', '=', 'related_event')->with('entity.event');
        }])->findOrFail($id);
```

Но так выводится только один items.

Если так

```
  $basket = Basket::with('items.entity')->with(['items' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('entity_type', '=', 'related_event')->with('entity.event');
    }])->with(['items' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('entity_type','<>', 'related_event')->with('entity');
    }])->findOrFail($id);
```

То, та пропадет первый items.

Если я делаю так

```
$basket = Basket::with('items.entity')->with('entity.event')->findOrFail($id)
```

То выпадает ошибка на других моделях, т.к там нет зависимости event.

Как можно правильно это реализовать, в basket_items используется полиморфная связь. Может можно как-то проверять, если ли такое отношение, если такого отношения нет, то просто не выводить его?

**UPD**

На скрине вывод происходит вот так:

```
$basket = Basket::with('items.entity')->findOrFail($id);
```

Answer (score 1):

Если у тебя есть модель BasketItem, ты можешь сделать так :

```
protected $appends    = ['city','entity']; 

public function getCityAttribute() {
    return $this->city;
}

public function getEntityAttribute() {
    return $this->entity
}
```

Но минус тут в кол-ве запросов в базу. 
Если ты это делаешь для выдачи данных по API возможно тебе проще собрать через join и сделать обертку через [Fractal](http://fractal.thephpleague.com/), собственно есть [пакет для Laravel](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-fractal)